# upvoted gained only 4 reputation

Tags: support, up-votes

I notice something weird today.
I got a single upvote and no downvote on an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9167676/601179) that I answered, and the reputation I earned is **4** instead of **10**.

Is this a bug?

**Screen shots:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could it be because you've reached the rep cap for that day?

Comment: Looks like​‌ it.

Comment: ummm. Yes I got **284** repution and 15*6 = **90** are from accepted answers so the last upvote gained me only **4** to because of the **200** cap. Sorry It was my first time... Thanks